# What are the timestamps in the logs in a Crashlytics report?

Tags: ios, crashlytics

For example, I see timestamps like `00:00:00:245` in my Crashlytics logs,  when using `CLS_LOG`.

Answer (score 3):

The timestamps are time from when that app session started, starting from `00:00:00:000`. For example, a timestamp of `00:01:43:000` happened 1 minute, 43 seconds after that app session started.

The time at the top of the Crashlytics crash page is when the crash occurred. If the last log line has a timestamp of 1 minute and that's around when the crash occurred, then the start of the logs is 1 minute before when the crash occurred. For example, if the crash occurred at 9:45am and the last log line is right before the crash and it has a timestamp of 1 minute, that app session started at 9:44am.